# Шейдер, создающий эффект черной дыры, которая искажает вокруг себя пространство и притягивает, неправильно работает

Tags: glsl

Пытаюсь сделать шейдер, создающий эффект черной дыры, которая искажает вокруг себя пространство и притягивает. Сделал формулу отобразив её на [данном графике](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3i04mqihmq),[image]
тут ясно видно, что "y" будет в диапазоне от 0.0 до 1.0 (небольшие погрешности не страшны). Полностью перенёс эту формулу в [новый шейдер в shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WlyfzW), перепроверил всё сотни раз, пробовал вычислять разными способами (проводя математические операции над простыми числами, а не над векторами) но всё тщетно. Почему то на (0.5, 0.5) находится пиксель с текстуры (0.0, 0.0).

([сам шейдер и код](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WlyfzW))

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    vec4 col = texture(iChannel0, pow(uv -.5, vec2(.6)) * .76 + .5);
    fragColor = col;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Иными словамии, скопипастите пожалуйста код и формулу в сам вопрос.

Comment: У вас отрицательные числа возводятся в нецелую степень. Задумайтесь, как это должно работать.

Comment: а, видеокарта оказывается не поддерживает возведение в степень отрицательных чисел... Напишите пожалуйста ответ, и я отвечу его как верный, спасибо.

Comment: Тут дело не столько в видеокарте. Она не умеет возводить отрицательные числа в целую степень - это да, неудобно. Но у вас степень нецелая. Например, чему равно `(-0.5)^0.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLSL [не умеет](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A647%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C370.89%2Cnull%5D) возводить отрицательные числа в степень, даже в целую. А у вас степень вообще нецелая...